# CAS Authentication failed! in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cas

I am implementing CAS module in drupal 7 . I am new working with CAS . After configuring the module when I try to log-in through cas in drupal it gives me the error

CAS Authentication failed!

You were not authenticated.

You may submit your request again by clicking here.

If the problem persists, you may contact the administrator of this site.

And when I check drupal log I get this error

CAS_AuthenticationException: in CAS_Client->validateCAS20() (line 2764 of E:\sites\sentosacove\sites\all\modules\cas\CAS\CAS\Client.php).

I am new in drupal 7 as well so I did not figure out how to solve this

Thanks is advance for any help .

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have a CAS server setup and working properly?
2. Did you follow this instruction https://www.drupal.org/project/cas to setup Drupal/CAS?

If so, please post your configurations.
FYI, I followed instruction and it worked.

Thai

Comment: I figured out the error it was  SSL certification problem

Comment: Hi @Ron i m facing the same issue. Can you provide the solution what you used to resolve this.

Comment: Hi @Tyagi I have the issue in my SSL certification where the certificate path was for my localhost rather that the server path where I was working.Other than this if you do the configuration properly it will work